# How can I display a profile stored in a database after a SQL query in a Google Spreadsheet Sidebar?

Tags: html, sql, css, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically here is what I'm doing:

- Storing a person profile in a MYSQL Database
- Creating a google spreadsheet add-on with a sidebar
- giving to the user the possibility to search profiles through the DB in the add-on
- giving to the user the possibility to display the datas of the profile in the Sidebar in the add-on

So Imagine you want to search **John** but the input you've entered in the searchbar is the letter **J**. The result of this query will be **Jack** , **Johnatan**, **Jules**, **Joe** and **John** as they all have a **J**. All this names will appear as link for you to click on in order to have more datas displayed (age, picture, fullname, description...). Only problem is that the only way I've managed to achieve is by making a SQL query after each keyup in my HTML input then create **X** numbers (in this case 5) of hidden classes with the infos, that I can show by clicking on a created link.

So this can easily work for 5 results, but imagine there's 100 of them and you only want to see one of them. Sounds crazy to create 100 hidden divs with all the infos to finally show only one.

here is an example code

code.gs

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('UI_HTML');
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

//My function to search for profiles (returns an array with each lines found)
function searchProfile(entry){
  var address = 'sql3.freemysqlhosting.net';
  var user = 'user';
  var userPwd = 'password';
  var db = 'sql12345678910';
  var instanceUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address;
  var dbUrl = instanceUrl + '/' + db;
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var ret = [];
  var res = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM item WHERE name = "' + entry + '"'
    + ' OR fullname LIKE CONCAT("%", "' + entry + '", "%")'
    + ' OR description LIKE CONCAT("%", "' + entry + '", "%")');
  var numCol = res.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  while (res.next())
  {
      j = 0;
      if (!ret[i])
          ret[i] = [];
      while (j < numCol)
      {
          ret[i][j]= res.getString(j + 1);
          j++;
      }
      i++;
   }
   return (ret);
}
```

UI_HTML.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .show {
                 display: block;
            }
            .hide {
                 display: none;
            }
         </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>
          <p>Search Profile</p>
          <input type="text" id="searchProfile" onkeyup="searchProfileHTML()" placeholder="Search for ...">
          <div id="results" ></div>
      </div>
      <script>
  function searchProfileHTML()
  {
    var x = document.getElementById("searchProfile").value;
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(createLinks)
        .searchProfile(x);
    function createLinks(result)
    {
      $('.links').remove();
      if (!x)
        return (0);
      $('#results').append('<ul></ul>');
      $('#results ul').addClass('links');
      result.forEach(function(el){
//My Link to show/hide my Div
        $('.links').append('<li><a id="' + el[0] + '-link" href="#">' + el[0] + '</a><div id="' + el[0] + '" class ="hide" ></div></li>');
//My div with all the infos (hidden by default)
        $('#' + el[0]).append(""
        + '<img src="' +  el[14] + '" height="100" width="100">'
        + "<div>"
          + "<ul>"
            + "<li>Name: "+ el[0] + "</li>"
            + "<li>Full name: "+ el[1] + "</li>"
            + "<li>Description : "+ el[2] + "</li>"
            + "<li>email: "+ el[3] + "</li>"
          + "</ul>"
        + "</div>");
        $('#' + el[0] + '-link').on("click", function(){
          $('#' + el[0]).toggleClass("hide show");
        })
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Anyone has an idea how I can make this more lite?

Comment: This is a fairly broad question.  Perhaps you could provide some code to show us what you have done.

Comment: You can fetch all user data from your database before the page is loaded and store it locally as JSON in the browser using sessionStorage or localStorage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage  You may then execute queries against the stored data. Of course, the downside is potential read-write conflicts that must be handled (imagine if someone deleted or modified the record a user is viewing)

Comment: Not sure to unerstand the downside problem. Can you develop please. Now if my datas are stored on local storage I'll still need to hide divs no? Thanks

Comment: You are the developer, not @Anton . You'll have to implement local or session storage if you want it in your application. I think it's reasonable to only show 5-10 matches, even if there are 100 for the current query. If the user can improve the quality, then their choice becomes available. Alternately, supply page markers to limit on-screen data, for the cases where the query cannot be improved

Comment: Sorry, it's impossible to understand what you mean without seeing your code. My approach would have been to write client-side JS scripts that build UI on the fly, based on search query results. Since I don't know what your approach is, there's no way for me to know which 'divs' you are talking about.  Perhaps you could break this into multiple questions. The issue with caching is that if someone updates the records in the database while you are viewing them in the sidebar, the cached data may become obsolete.

Comment: oh ok thank you @AntonDementiev now I understand what you meant with the database change. I'll try posting a code example but I'm afraid it will be a bit long.

Comment: @AntonDementiev  I've just added some code. Thanks in advance

Comment: StackOverflow is for asking specific programming questions the answers to which may be helpful to others. If you'd like to have others build an ad-hoc solution tailored to your needs, consider hiring someone. I've already outlined the general approach in the previous comment. What is it about this approach that you don't understand? If there are issues you are struggling with, break the problem into multiple questions

Comment: Sorry I didn't meant to bother. If my question is too broad or unclear that's to bad I'll handle that a different manner. Thanks anyway